# ng new got stuck on npm install - windows

Tags: angular

I added a new Angular project using the command line "ng new ProjectName --skip-install"
However, once few files are created the command prompt gets stuck on the line "Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ...K52tUz93o\nto9tntnlPK". So basically only few files are installed and is an incomplete installation altogether.

Things I tried include uninstalling/installing node and npm. However that did not seem to help.
Another option I tried was to execute the command "ng new ApplicationName" and even in that scenario I was getting issues of incomplete installation. Please advice, I have attached screenshot as well.

Also I have provided my current versions of npm, angular and node (image attached)[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you working in VPN ? may be the the sites are blocked. I would suggest you to come out of VPN and then try.

Comment: No, i am not connecting via VPN.

Comment: See, if you are able to reach this site: `https://www.npmjs.com/`. this is the place from where the URL referencing happens. from there, the npm packages are inturn loaded from `github`

Comment: Yes, i am able to reach this site, however still no success

Answer (score 0):

Folow the below steps:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: I did update the angular cli to the latest version, however it does not help. Got the same error once cli was updated.

Comment: If i dont specify --skip-install and execute ng new application i get below error in cli

- Installing packages...npm WARN deprecated tslint@6.1.2: TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint.@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...s/browserify":"latest'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\kk\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-13T11_20_19_933Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Answer (score 0):

1. check for your internet connection wether it is stable or not when you are doing **ng new** or just try it on any other network (like Neighbors WIFI):)
2. 

```
npm cache clean --force
```

run this in PowerShell or for me it was in
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

Comment: I am connecting via my mobile phone network (hotspot), since i am currently not having any other option

Comment: I dont know why but a good connection is always needed while creating a new project also i got these errors whenever i was on mobile network..switching network worked or else try doing npm cache clean --force until it works..

Answer (score 0):

Found [below solution from angular CLI issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17447)

1. first of all, uninstall node js and npm Also Angular.

```
npm uninstall -g    
@angular/cli npm cache clean --force     
npm install -g @angular/cli@8.0.0
```

2. then update angular latest version It will work

Comment: I actually did uninstall/reinstall npm and node couple of times, same with angular cli too

Comment: When i execute the command "D:\Angular Projects\src>ng new AngularTrialApplicationOne"
After installing few files, the command line gets stuck at 
Installing Packages...and does not end (hence npm packages are not installed)